# How to Handle different JSON response types from same endpoint in RetroFit 2

Tags: android

This is my json api :- https://test324y.highape.com/api/get_homepage_data?token=xyz123

As you can see it has many objects with different types.
When i paste it to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ it gives me multiple class .

I want to know how do i set data to those model class using retrofit from same end point ?

Comment: its ok if it gives u multiple classes. just use the root class with your retrofit . later u can navigate the root model class to go to data/class u need data from

Comment: can you explain this in a bit details ?

Comment: sure image u want to have data in USER class but user class has object of address . So u can pass USER as a response object type to retrofit. and once retrofit give u user , u can access user.getAddress() to get your address object.Retrofit will take the root object class to be parsable from the response

Comment: Since you used `jsonschema2pojo` your root class will be called `Example` by default and since your json root is an array you should be  calling it like `Call<List<Example>>` from **retrofit2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after generating Pojos from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
you will get a class for every object in the response. but you will only use the class that's called **Example** with retrofit. and later you can access all response value through it.

And of course rename your response class to something more related to the endpoint. e.g **"HomePageResponse"**

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("featured_events")
@Expose
private FeaturedEvents featuredEvents;
@SerializedName("trending_events")
@Expose
private TrendingEvents trendingEvents;
@SerializedName("popular_activities")
@Expose
private PopularActivities popularActivities;
@SerializedName("event_count")
@Expose
private EventCount eventCount;
@SerializedName("offers")
@Expose
private Offers offers;
@SerializedName("venues")
@Expose
private Venues venues;
@SerializedName("artists")
@Expose
private Artists artists;

public FeaturedEvents getFeaturedEvents() {
return featuredEvents;
}

public void setFeaturedEvents(FeaturedEvents featuredEvents) {
this.featuredEvents = featuredEvents;
}

public TrendingEvents getTrendingEvents() {
return trendingEvents;
}

public void setTrendingEvents(TrendingEvents trendingEvents) {
this.trendingEvents = trendingEvents;
}

public PopularActivities getPopularActivities() {
return popularActivities;
}

public void setPopularActivities(PopularActivities popularActivities) {
this.popularActivities = popularActivities;
}

public EventCount getEventCount() {
return eventCount;
}

public void setEventCount(EventCount eventCount) {
this.eventCount = eventCount;
}

public Offers getOffers() {
return offers;
}

public void setOffers(Offers offers) {
this.offers = offers;
}

public Venues getVenues() {
return venues;
}

public void setVenues(Venues venues) {
this.venues = venues;
}

public Artists getArtists() {
return artists;
}

public void setArtists(Artists artists) {
this.artists = artists;
}

}
```

your endpoint will be something like this.

```
@GET("get_homepage_data")
Call<Example> getExample(@Query("token") String token);
```

Endpoint call example

```
   Call<Example> call = api.getExample(token);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            Example example = response.body();
            // use example object to get any value you want

        } 

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HyperResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            if (t != null && t.getMessage() != null)
                Log.e("Failure", "Example Failure" + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: How will I set data to Featured event, tending events and other classes ? Will retrofit do it or i will have to do it manually onResponse ?

Comment: Retrofit handle this by itself. you only have to include all classes that you need and give retrofit base class.

Comment: i have included example in the answer. you can use example object to  access Featured event, tending events and other classes you want.

Comment: List<HomeDatum> homeData=response.body();




                System.out.println("adasd"+homeData.get(0).getVenues().getQty().toString());    This is giving null pointer error

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using only one model class for parsing the response using Retrofit.

Example:
Create a model class say `Response.java` which contains following model classes:

1. FeaturedEvents
2. TrendingEvents
3. PopularActivities
4. Offers
5. Venues
6. Artists

All above model classes contain respective data. This way you can easily parse the response and If API excludes any model in response, then parsed value for that model will be `null`. You should always check it before showing it in UI.

Hope this will help!